# JSON parse with replaceable values

Tags: json, syntax

Is there currently any syntax to allow for replaceable values in a .json ?

If not I would propose to have this capability.
After all this is 2022 shouldn't we be able to populate values easily without have to write our own parsers?

simple example:

{
"%h" : "some value",
}

this would replace "%h" with the system specific hostname, and would be completely option, if the "parameter" does not exist, no change in the parse.

And if .json has a specific "parameter" syntax that is native to them, that's fine.
Just the idea, we could have this option,  "%h", or "", whatever syntax .json would like.

Comment: \<hostname\>  was the 2nd example

Comment: JSON is a "static" format, by itself it cannot change its contents. You will need to write some code in some programming language to achieve this.

Comment: I understand that.

Comment: This would not change the format of the .json structure, it would just make the values dynamic.

Comment: Where would i propose, such a modification ?

Comment: [This](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) is the RFC for the JSON format, if you want something changed you can contact the entity responsible. But I doubt you'll succeed, since by definition JSON is static, so if you need something dynamic then you'll need another format.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON standard does not allow for dynamic values. It is a very simple text representation format meant for encoding data interchange [the standard publcation](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/) describes it like this:

> JSON is a lightweight, text-based, language-independent syntax for defining data interchange formats. It was derived from the ECMAScript programming language, but is programming language independent. JSON defines a small set of structuring rules for the portable representation of structured data.
>
> The goal of this specification is only to define the syntax of valid JSON texts. Its intent is not to provide any semantics or interpretation of text conforming to that syntax. It also intentionally does not define how a valid JSON text might be internalized into the data structures of a programming language. There are many possible semantics that could be applied to the JSON syntax and many ways that a JSON text can be processed or mapped by a programming language. Meaningful interchange of information using JSON requires agreement among the involved parties on the specific semantics to be applied. Defining specific semantic interpretations of JSON is potentially a topic for other specifications. Similarly, language mappings of JSON can also be independently specified. For example, ECMA-262 defines mappings between valid JSON texts and ECMAScript’s runtime data structures.

Therefore there is no way to define a template value of some sort. You can achieve such functionality by processing your JSON separately but that would depend on the technology stack and the tools you use. However, it would only work for your project, not in any other third party projects.